# Understanding @specialized with Non-Primitives

Tags: scala

Looking at `@specialized`'s [docs](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.specialized), I see:

```
scala> class MyList[@specialized T]
defined class MyList
```

My incomplete understanding is that `MyList` accepts a generic parameter, `T`, that **must** be a primitive.

```
scala> new MyList[Int] {}
res1: MyList[Int] = $anon$1@17884d
```

But, I then made a case class.

```
scala> case class Zig(x: String)
defined class Zig
```

However, given my above assumption, I did not expect to be able to `new` a **MyList** with a parameterized type of `Zig`.

```
scala> new MyList[Zig]
res2: MyList[Zig] = MyList@62de73eb
```

What am I missing?

Comment: helpful answer on the [non/spire](https://github.com/non/spire) google groups - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spire-math/HGorcOyGDP0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The @specialized annotation adds in additional implementations of the class (hidden away in the bytecode), that are implemented in such away as to avoid wrapping primitive types. In terms of Java they'd use int rather than Integer, as the constant wrapping and unwrapping can be quite bad for performance.

But it still retains the implementation that you write that can take any type.